# Facebook SDK .NET - (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a message to a Facebook page from a C# web application.  I am getting the following exception thrown on calling `FacebookClient.Post(...)`:

> **FacebookOAuthException** (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this action

Code:

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
facebookClient.AppId = appId;
facebookClient.AppSecret = appSecret;

if (Request["code"] == null)
{
    var authUrl = facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(new
    {
        client_id = appId,
        client_secret = appSecret,
        scope = "publish_stream",
        redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    });

    Response.Redirect(authUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
else
{
    dynamic result = facebookClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new
    {
        client_id = appId,
        client_secret = appSecret,
        grant_type = "client_credentials",
        redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
        code = Request["code"]
    });

    facebookClient.AccessToken = result.access_token;
    // Store access token
}
```

Sending a message:

```
protected void PublishMessage(string message)
{
    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

    client.AppId = ApplicationId;
    client.AppSecret = ApplicationSecret;

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = message;

    client.Post(PageName + "/feed", parameters);
}
```

I accept the following Facebook prompts to ensure that the app has access:

[image]

[image]

And in my Facebook profile settings, the app looks like this:

[image]

I am using the Facebook SDK for .NET v6.4.2 (the latest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem a silly question, but aren't you missing the Request code from your access token request? Shouldn't it be like this?

```
dynamic result = facebookClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = appId,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    grant_type = "authorization_code"
    redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
    code = Request["code"]
});
```

**Edit** Just realized, you have to use a different grant_type when using the request code :)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! I must have gone through this code 100 times already.  But unfortunately it's still not working.  I get the exact same error.  Any further ideas?

Comment: Hmm, Ive seen a few examples where after you get the access token back, you instantiate a new Facebook object with the token passed in as a parameter to the constructor, then all further calls are made with this new instance. Although I am not sure why this would make a difference :(

Comment: I'm essentially doing that (question edited with code).  Sad face indeed :(

Comment: Just added an edit. Sorry I didnt notice your grant_type on the first look through. Im pretty sure that should work now :)

Comment: THANK YOU!  So what is "client_credentials" meant for?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/oauth/token) is a good summary. These arnt Facebook specific, but oauth documentation none the less. Explains it quite well