# can't post on facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to post on my wall using c# api but always have error 200 OAuth problem

```
string accessToken = token; //last 2months
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.name = "My name";
parameters.description = "";
client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

What am I missing?

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: How are you declaring and setting the value for `token`?

Comment: does this help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573458/facebook-sdk-net-200-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform) ?

Comment: i used this link which need 3 parametres, appId public, appID private and temporal token: [link](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=public_id&client_secret=secret id&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=temporal_token)

Comment: What does your login code look like? Are you requesting permission to publish on behalf of the user?

Comment: You need to request the `publish_actions` permission!

Comment: how i request the publish_actions permission? In the app details section --> App Center Permissions i enabled publish_actions